# Flask allow chunked data or use different library?

Tags: python, flask, rasa-core

Hi I am working on a python rasa chatbot project that uses the following code tutorial: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/issues/119 to allow posts calls to the rasa framework. I am running into an issue where if the post call comes in chunks, python is not able to accept this. Is there a way to accept chunked data through Flask or would you recommend a different webhook library? Thank you in advance!

Python:

```
class SimpleWebBot(HttpInputComponent):
"""A simple web bot that listens on a url and responds."""

def blueprint(self, on_new_message):
    custom_webhook = Blueprint('custom_webhook', __name__)
    CORS(custom_webhook)

    @custom_webhook.route("/webhook", methods=['POST'])
    def receive():
        payload = request.json
        sender_id = payload.get("sender", None)
        text = payload.get("message", None)
        out = CollectingOutputChannel()
        on_new_message(UserMessage(text, out, sender_id))
        responses = [m for _, m in out.messages]
        return jsonify(responses)
```

Comment: Blueprints are not related in any way with chucked request, they are the way of organizing a code into modules. Please rewrite your question [following this guide advises](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion chunked calls to the input channel don't make any sense. 
The payload you are sending to the input channel of Rasa Core should be quite small. Typically they include

- a sender id
- some authorization headers
- the user message to the bot

This should be in the size of a few kilo bytes, which makes the use of chunked requests inefficient.